# PHP Exec hostgator

Tags: php, exec

I have this script to execute a file on my server hostgator. I launch this script (script.php)

```
<?php


echo exec('whoami');

 if(function_exists('exec')) {
          echo "exec is enabled";
           }




$output = array();

$retval = null;

echo "<br>SONO IN HOME  000000000000000<br>";

echo exec('HOME=/home1/my username on hostgator/public_html/path to script/provaricevimento.php' , $output, $retval);





if ($retval == 0) {

echo "<br>Valore " . $output ."<br>";
echo "<br>Valore 0 " . $output[0] ."<br>";
echo "<br>Valore 1 " . $output[1] ."<br>";
echo "<br>Valore 2 " . $output[2] ."<br>";
echo "<br>Valore 3 " . $output[3] ."<br>";
echo "<br>Valore 4 " . $output[4] ."<br>";
echo "<br>Valore 5 " . $output[5] ."<br>";


}   

else{

echo "Error issuing exec command! valore ritorno:".$retval."<br>";



}   

echo "<br>-----------retval :$retval ------------------<br>";
print_r ($output);

echo "<br>-----------------------------<br>";

?>
```

and provaricevimento.php is

```
<?php

include '../connessione/conn.php';


$data=date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

//$ric=$_GET['ricevimento'];

//$testo=$_GET['testo'];

//$url=$_GET['url'];
//$data= date("m.d.y");


$sql="INSERT INTO prova SET 
        testo='$testo',
        url='$ric',
        data='$data'";







        if (@mysql_query($sql)){

            echo "INSERIMENTO CON SUCCESSO: con conta : $conta e i :$i<br>";

    } else

    {

            echo "inserimento NON avvenuto".mysql_error()."<br>";

    }







?>
```

All is ok, return code is 0,  but i see that the file script.php doesn't execute provaricevimento.php  ,  because the table is not update, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Well I think instead of this line:

```
echo exec('HOME=/home1/my username on hostgator/public_html/path to script/provaricevimento.php' , $output, $retval);
```

You should probably call the script using PHP, not changing the Home variable:

```
echo exec('php5 /home1/my username on hostgator/public_html/path to script/provaricevimento.php' , $output, $retval);
```

However I don't see why you can't just use PHP's `include` instead.

Comment: sorry , i have seen only now. I don't know the reason but now HOME = is right, i don't know why.  I must use exec because i must update a database in real time, so i have no choice. Anyway , what's the different with php5 ?

Comment: Well, it's a PHP script so when in the terminal you would use the 'php' (or 'php5') program to run it.
However, seeing as you're running it with PHP anyway, you shouldn't need to use `exec`! You can just use this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: i know this function and i 've read on php.net , but i don't understand  how is possible to use it in my problem. In Hostgar i use cron job that call a database that call the function exec , so i 've somenthing similar to to real time, can i do the same thing with the "include" ? Now all is ok, but  i don't like  my solution to resolve my problem , so if  there is some alternative solution i want to lear it.

Comment: You should just be able to call `include '/home1/my username on hostgator/public_html/path to script/provaricevimento.php'` and it will run the `provaricevimento.php` just fine.